# Flexible array error with gcc 6 but not with gcc 4

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, struct

I'm trying to compile a piece of code written by a colleague. On my machine with gcc 6.1.1 I get this error:

```
In file included from src/TYAGlobalLibs.cc:1:0:
./include/TYAGlobalLibs.hh:112:17: error: flexible array member ‘TYA::TMultiHist::fh’ not at end of ‘class TYA::TMultiHist’
 TH1F    *fh[];
             ^
./include/TYAGlobalLibs.hh:102:9: note: in the definition of ‘class TYA::TMultiHist’
class TMultiHist{
      ^~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems that this is a forbidden code path and as such it triggers a compiler error; however, using gcc 4.5.2 the same file compiles without error. I use these compiler options for g++:

```
-O2 -Wall -fPIC -pthread -m32 -std=c++98
```

for both 6.1.1 and for 4.5.2. In case it matters, gcc 6 runs on a 64 bit machine while gcc 4 on a 32 bit one. Here's a minimal code snippet to reproduce the issue:

```
struct test{
        int a;
        float b[];
        double c;
};

int main(){     
}
```

Does anybody know why this happens and eventually if there are compiler options to make gcc 6 compile without errors (I have no chance of changing the code, it's not under my control)?

Comment: Please include the code in the question, or at least a code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: In C, a flexible array member (added in C99) must be the last member of a structure. It doesn't make sense to have a member following an FAM, since that member's offset couldn't be determined. I don't believe C++ permits flexible array members, but apparently g++ permits them as an extension. If g++ 4.5.2 permitted a flexible array member other than as the last member of a class or struct, that was a bug in g++ 4.5.2. Find out who controls the code and get them to fix it.

Comment: g++ before 6 simply regards this as a zero size array (an extension to the C++ language). -Wpedantic triggers a warning. Such an array cannot be really used for anything if it's not the last one in the class. Perhaps you should ask your colleague to use standard C++ for the sake of portability.

Comment: Also note that g++ now does not warn about using flexible array members (when they used last in a class) even with -Wpedantic, which is [a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71290).

Comment: You have to add `-pedantic-errors` to get GCC to behave as a proper standard compiler. Without that option, it is very lax and allows all kinds of weird things.

Comment: @Lundin: understood, thanks. But still I don't understand why gcc 6 gives an error while gcc 4 not. Maybe gcc 6 enables -pedantic-errors by default? Sounds strange to me but...

Comment: This is because pre-6.0 gcc treated flexible array members and zero size arrays the same, now they are different (as explained in the bug report). If you replace `[]` with `[0]` gcc-5.x doesn't care, but gcc 6.x will give a different message (warning, not error). In any case this is a dubious construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C (C99 and later), a *flexible array member* can be defined with `[]`, and must be the last member of a structure.  C++ doesn't support flexible array members, but g++ permits them as a language extension.

Older versions of g++ do not require a flexible array member to be the last member of a class or struct.  This is a bug, which has been corrected in newer versions of g++.

Here's a small test program, based on yours that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

static int mem[100];

struct test{
        int a;
        int b[];
        int c;
};

int main(){     
    test *ptr = (test*)&mem;
    ptr->a = 10;
    ptr->b[0] = 20;
    ptr->b[1] = 30;
    ptr->c = 40;

    std::cout << "ptr->a    = " << ptr->a << "\n";
    std::cout << "ptr->b[0] = " << ptr->b[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "ptr->b[1] = " << ptr->b[1] << "\n";
    std::cout << "ptr->c    = " << ptr->c << "\n";
}
```

And here's the output when I compile it with g++ 4.1.2:

```
ptr->a    = 10
ptr->b[0] = 40
ptr->b[1] = 30
ptr->c    = 40
```

As you can see, the member `c` is allocated at the same offset as `b[0]`.

(Strictly speaking, using an `int[]` array to hold a `test` object isn't 100% safe due to possible alignment problems, but that's unlikely to be an issue in practice.)

It's very likely that your code has undiscovered bugs because of this.

Your problem is not that the newer g++ rejects your code; it's that the older one doesn't.

Reordering the member declarations so the flexible array member appears last is the simplest fix -- though you (or someone else) will need to carefully examine how the type is used.  A far better solution is probably to replace the flexible array member with some C++ container class, perhaps a `std::vector`.

> (I have no chance of changing the code, it's not under my control)

*Somebody* is able to change the code, and presumably you're able to submit a bug report.